# Sharepoint 2013 REST queries filter items gives error?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, rest

I using Sharepoint 2013 I want to get list items using Sharepoint 2013 REST feature

I can get all items but when i put my filter it does not works I don't know where the problem is.

my code:

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="txtbox1" id="txtbox1" />
<input type="button" value="test it works" onclick="load_sls($('#txtbox1').val());" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function load_sls(province)
{
    var call =$.ajax({
    url: "http://server/sites/test/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Agency')/items? $select=Id,Title?$filter=[Title eq '"+province+"']",
    type: "GET",
    data: JSON,
    headers: { 

        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",

    }
    //success: doSuccess,
    //error: doError
 });
call.done(function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
    alert('success'+jqXHR.responseText);
});
call.fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
    alert('Error occured'+jqXHR.responseText);
});
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The endpoint in your example contains some typos:

1. Replace `?$filter` into `&$filter`
2. Remove `[` and `]` symbols from `filter` query option since they are
   not supported

The fixed url:

```
url: "http://server/sites/test/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Agency')/items?$select=Id,Title&$filter=Title eq '"+province+"'"
```

**Further improvements**

1. Use `encodeURIComponent` function to escape characters, for example:

   ```
   var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Pages')/items?$select=Id,Title&$filter=Title eq '" + encodeURIComponent(pageTitle) + "'";
   ```
2. Prefer [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) over [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to perform read
   operation, for example:

   ```
   var getListItems =  function (webUrl,listTitle) {
       var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/items";
       return $.getJSON(url,function( data ) {
              return data; 
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: Great answer thanks. please answer this question also: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118633/how-to-select-and-filter-list-items-lookup-column-with-sharepoint-2013-rest-feat/118637

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the '?' before the $filter to a '&'

To something like this:

```
http://server/sites/test/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Agency')/items?$select=Id,Title&$filter=[Title eq '"+province+"']"
```