# How to select and filter list items lookup column with Sharepoint 2013 REST Feature?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, rest

I am using SharePoint 2013 REST.
I have list which contains many look up columns, I can get list items through list if they are not look up columns but I can't select and also filter based on look up columns.

for example my list have 4 columns 2 are look up column:

Title, Company, Province

Where province is a look up field how can I select filter my data based on province field ?

which is a look up field it gives error.

My REST Code:

```
    $.ajax({
       url: "https://Myserver.com/sites/ibs/omt/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Test')/items?$select=Title,Province/ID&$expand=Province/ID&$filter=Province eq'"+province +"'",
       type: "GET",
       headers: {
          "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
       },
       success: function(data){
          $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item){
            //$('#first_data').html(item.Title);
            $('.int_extras').append("<a style='font-weight:bold; color:#FFFFFF;margin:2px;' href='"+links+item.ID+"'>"+item.Title+"</a><br />");
         });
      },
      error: function(error){
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
      }
   )};
```

I am new to REST queries please give your examples in details

Comment: The end of your call is ')};' where it should be : '});'

Answer (score 29):

### How to filter by lookup field value using SharePoint REST

Assume a `Contacts` list that contains a lookup field named `Province`

**Option 1**

Once a lookup column is getting added into list, its `ID` become accessible automatically via ListItem resource. For example, when the field named `{field-name}` is added into List, it's value could be set or get via `{field-name}Id` property of List Item.

The following query demonstrate how to filter list items by *lookup field Id* (`Province Id` in our case):

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Contacts')/items?$filter=ProvinceId eq <ProvinceId>
```

where `<ProvinceId>` is a province id

**Option 2**

In order to filter by *lookup value*, the query should contain `$expand` query option to retrieve projected fields (like `Province Title`). The following example demonstrates how to filter by *lookup field value* (by `Province Title` in our case):

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Contacts')/items?$select=Province/Title&$expand=Province&$filter=Province/Title eq <ProvinceTitle>
```

where `<ProvinceTitle>` is a Title of Province

Comment: My new query: "https://Myserver.com/sites/ias/omt/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Test')/items?$select=Province/Province&$expand=Province&$filter=Province/Province eq'"+province+"'",                                      when I write it in browser it gives this error: The field or property 'Province' does not exist

Comment: This error occurs since there is no field named Province in Province list (projected list). To filter by Province Title use the following query: /_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Contacts')/items?$select=Province/Title&$expand=Province&$filter=Province/Title eq 'A'

Comment: Pay attention to expression Province/Title that means get Title field from Province list, in your case it is Province/Province what means get Province field from Province list

Comment: even I can't select my code is blow: https://MyServer/sites/ias/omt//_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items?$select=Province/Province&$expand=Province            gives error:  The field or property 'Province' does not exist.

Comment: once again, it says: there is NO field named Province in Province List, try to replace to Province/Title

Comment: That is also not working I tried

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18033/discussion-between-mehdi-jalal-and-vadim-gremyachev).

Comment: Please create 2 List one Test and second Province the Test list should have one column Title and a look up column Province which will be linked to Province List Title try to get data from Test list based on Province Look up column

Comment: Unfortunately i cant reproduce your error, could you please verify the following request:  /_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Test')/items?$select=ProvinceId

Comment: Gives error:  <m:message xml:lang="en-US">The field or property 'ProvinceId' does not exist.</m:message>

Comment: So what is the solution for this? I am too facing the same problem.

Comment: has anyone found a solution for this? i am currently stuck with the same error :/ I also tried adding look up columns such as ID and Title but to no avail :/

Answer (score 4):

your REST Service Call should be like

```
 url: "https://Myserver.com/sites/ibs/omt/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Test')/items?$select=Title,Province/ID&$expand=Province&$filter=Province/ID eq '"+province +"'"
```

It will work for you as while filtering you need to specify field followed by your look up column name

Answer (score 2):

I have recently posted an article on [Cascading drop down in SharePoint using REST API](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2017/06/cascading-drop-down-in-sharepoint.html).

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + drinkTypeListName + "')/items?$select=Title,Drink/Title,Drink/Id&$expand=Drink&$filter=Drink/Title eq '" + selectedDrink + "'";
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my RestUrl-

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Questions')/items?&$filter=Language eq '1'
```

Details- In this it is fetching all the items in questions List which is having specific languageId. LanguageId is defined from language list having lookup in Question list. Question List contains a lookup column ie "language" for language List.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Connell covers the solution to this very thoroughly in his blog here: http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/Applying-Filters-to-Lookup-Fields-with-the-SP2013-REST-API

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.