# Get Columns via REST

Tags: 2013, rest

I'm trying to get a list of all columns/fields for a list via REST using the `/_api/Web/Lists(guid'xxxx')/Fields` endpoint.  This works fine, except it's adding in all of the system and duplicate fields such as LinkTitle, LinkTitleNoMenu, ContentTypeId, etc.

Short of filtering it out after retrieval using `$.grep`, is there a way I could use the filter syntax or similar to have SharePoint just return the user columns from a list, i.e. the ones a user might see in an edit or display form?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to get the fields from a specific Content Type (`/Lists.../ContentTypes/.../Fields)`? That is after all what the user would see in a form

Comment: @eirikb - Maybe. Vadim's answer works well for me but I'll keep this one in mind for future use.  I like the idea.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could apply the following filter to exclude the fields that are not available in List forms:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/fields?$filter=Hidden eq false and ReadOnlyField eq false
```

Comment: This worked great. I was attempting to also filter out ContentType and Attachments, but none of the additional filters seemed to work.  I can live with just filtering out those two client side.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All system fields in SharePoint have a SourceId of "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" defined in their SchemaXml. Any user defined fields will have a Guid. So you can filter using this to return just the user defined ones:

$filter= substringof('SourceID=\"{',SchemaXml)

Comment: Clever.  I ended up getting the idea to work with `/_api/Web/Lists(guid'xxxx')/Fields?$filter=substringof(%27http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3%27,SchemaXml)%20eq%20false` as the URL.  Unfortunately it also removed the Title field, which I need.

Comment: Just add an additional filter for Title: &$filter= ((substringof('SourceID=\"{',SchemaXml)) or (Title eq 'Title'))

Answer (score 1):

this is working well for me:

```
/_api/web/Lists(guid '<your list guid here>')/Fields?$select=Title,InternalName&$filter=Hidden eq false and ReadOnlyField eq false and InternalName ne 'Attachments' and InternalName ne 'ContentType'
```

Answer (score -1):

For instance, My list is like below.

Column1  Column2
Valuea1  Valuea2
Valueb1  Valueb2
Valuec1  Valuec2

Using Rest, If i want to filter a column by its value, Lets say Filter Column1 by the Value 'Valueb1'., then endpoint is

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items?$filter=Column1 eq 'Valueb1'
```

This will work for One Column only. But if I wanted to include more than one column in such a filtering condition, The EndPoint is

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items?$filter=Column1 eq 'Valuea1’ &$filter=Column2 eq 'Valueb2’
```

Hope this would help you.

Comment: @ChrisRomp You can also check this link[http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/118659/28366]

Comment: The question is not how to filter list items by column, but how to get all list columns and filter out the system ones.