# Get columns type via REST

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, field-type

I successfully managed to get columns names but now I'm trying to get columns type via REST but surprisingly I didn't found something on it in documentations (or maybe I missed it).

It's really easy to get columns type via GUI but is it possible to get them via the REST API?

Comment: Look at this answer [Get Columns via REST](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/133245/get-columns-via-rest)

Comment: I had already seen this answer but what I want isn't columns names but columns types.

Comment: Column types, then look this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/how-to-get-the-list-columns-in-sharepoint-2013-online-using/ , but this Online...

Comment: This doesn't seem to be what I'm searching for.
I need to get columns type (text, date, personn, choice, ...) without any previous GUI operation(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below end point to get Columns and there datatypes
../_api/lists/getbytitle('Categories')/fields?$select=Title,TypeAsString,TypeDisplayName

Comment: The problem is that `../_api/lists/getbytitle('Categories')/fields` give me an error message : `"A node of type 'EndOfInput' was read from the JSON reader when trying to read the start of an entry. A 'StartObject' node was expected."`

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Praveen has a slight error in the URL. It should be

```
http://siteurl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/fields?$select=Title,TypeAsString,TypeDisplayName&$filter=InternalName eq 'Title'
```

Answer taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51033723/1047998).

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
GetListColumns = function (listName) {
     return jQuery.ajax({
         url: encodeURI(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/Fields?$filter=Hidden eq false and ReadOnlyField eq false"),
         type: "GET",
         headers: {
             "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
             "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
         },
     });
 }
```

usage:

```
GetListColumns('Categories').done(function (data) {console.log(data)})
```

Comment: Don't forget to include jQuery.